# Replicate applyExtraLightEffect iOS7 blur using GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, ios7, gpuimage

I followed this [excellent tutorial on how to replicate iOS7 style blur using GPUImage](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage). However the effect I'm looking for is the one produced by [`applyExtraLightEffect`](https://gist.github.com/neilkimmett/10145867#file-uiimage-imageeffects-m-L16) in Apple's sample code ([download here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=wwdc_2013/wwdc_2013_sample_code/ios_uiimageeffects.zip)).

I'm using a `GPUImageiOSBlurFilter` as follows:

```
UIImage *image = [view renderSnapshotImage];

if (!self.blurFilter) {
    self.blurFilter = [[GPUImageiOSBlurFilter alloc] init];
    self.blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 20.0f;
    self.blurFilter.saturation = 1.8f;
}

GPUImagePicture *picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
[picture addTarget:self.blurFilter];
[self.blurFilter addTarget:self.blurView];

[picture processImageWithCompletionHandler:^{
    [self.blurFilter removeAllTargets];
}];
```

In order to recreate the full effect with GPUImage I need to blend in a tintColor, which is done in UIImage+ImageEffects like so

```
// Add in color tint.
if (tintColor) {
    CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, tintColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(outputContext, imageRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
}
```

So essentially I need a GPUImage filter to blend in a solid colour, but I have no idea which one I need, or how to use it. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Since all they do is overlay that color, a GPUImageSolidColorGenerator fed into a GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter with your filter's output should replicate that exactly, but a simple brightness filter might be all you need to get close. Or you could create your own custom filter to just tint by a given color and strength.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm having trouble knowing what order to add the various targets in, here is what I have: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10254755

Comment: You need both the blur filter and the color generator to target the overlay blend (targeting the blur filter to the blend first, then the color generator). The color generator takes no input, but you must use -forceProcessingAtSize: to set its size to match that of your input image. Again, a custom filter that overlays a tint would be more performant and a little cleaner to use in the end.